# Replacing actual values by np.nan (if threshold is met) over a specific interval

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, nan, fillna

As an illustrative example, in the list below let's say that if a threshold value of 1.45 is reached I would like to fill the next remaining values with NaN until the next initial NaN values. In that case that'd means replacing 1.12 and 1.05 by np.nan.

`[1.02, 1.08, 1.45, 1.12, 1.05, nan, nan, nan, nan, 1.13, 1.2, 1.03]`

So expected results would be:

`[1.02, 1.08, 1.45, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 1.13, 1.2, 1.03]`

I'm actually working with DataFrame's columns but presumably the same logic would apply.
Is there any convenient ways of doing this ?

Comment: working on native `list`s will be slightly different than using a dataframe. I have posted an answer assuming, you need it for the latter.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

thresh = 1.45
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'col': [1.02, 1.08, 1.45, 1.12, 1.05, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1.13, 1.2, 1.03]})

firstThresh = df['col'].index[df['col']==thresh][0]
firstNan = df['col'].index[df['col'].apply(np.isnan)][0]
#print(firstThresh, firstNan)

df.at[firstThresh + 1 : firstNan, 'col'] = np.nan

print(df)
```

Will produce the desired result!

Comment: Kindly upvote/accept if this answers your question!